# phpcs keeps scanning the whole project and not the specified directory

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

I am trying to run PHP code sniffer on a specific directory, but PHP code sniffer is ignoring the `<files>` flag and scan the whole project.

Here is the command I am running:
`./vendor/bin/phpcs -p . --extensions=php docs/`

I am using the current version of PHP sniffer (3.4.0) and `docs/` is a real directory.

Comment: Why do you have that `.`? Can you try `./vendor/bin/phpcs -p  --extensions=php docs/`

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa ooh, that worked. thanks ‍♂️

Comment: You're welcome @robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

`./vendor/bin/phpcs -p --extensions=php docs/`